# How to remove duplication and add data to a new column

Tags: sql-server

I am still learning SQL and I'm working with the 'pubs' database. I'm trying to join a couple elements to a new ordered list.

```
SELECT t.title_id
    ,t.title
    ,DATEDIFF(dd, pubdate, GETDATE()) / 365 AS AantalJaren
    ,au.au_fname + ' ' + au.au_lname AS authorname
FROM titles t
LEFT JOIN titleauthor ta ON t.title_id = ta.title_id
LEFT JOIN authors au ON ta.au_id = au.au_id
WHERE t.title_id IN (
        SELECT title_id
        FROM titleauthor
        GROUP BY title_id
        HAVING COUNT(title_id) > 1
        )
ORDER BY t.title_id
```

It's hard to explain what I want so i'll just show it in images :

This is what I got : 
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PR5nZ.png]

This is what i'm trying to get : 
[image: http://prntscr.com/5ubo5x]

Comment: what if a book was written by two or more authors? you can't simply ignore one author and you shouldn't. what you do is group_concat them. this way you get one field with all authors instead replicated records.

Comment: Good question! 
Well... I'm realy new to this so I have no Idea how to do it on your way. 
I'll try to google it :)

Comment: if you are using mysql search for group_concat. also use sql fiddle to create your schema and post the link here so we can show you how to do it

Comment: I'm using MSQL.
Sorry for the mistake in my startpost

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for,

Sample Table Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE #Yourtable
(
    TITLEID VARCHAR(30),
    TITLE VARCHAR(100),
    AntalJaren INT,
    AUTHOR_NAME VARCHAR(30)
)

INSERT INTO #Yourtable VALUES
('BU1032',  'The Busy Executive''s Database Guide', 23, 'Maijorie Green'),
('BU1032',  'The Busy Executive''s Database Guide', 23, 'Abraham Bennet'),
('BU1111',  'Cooking with Computers: Surreptitious Balance Sheets', 23, 'Michael O''Leary'),
('BU1111',  'Cooking with Computers: Surreptitious Balance Sheets', 23, 'Steams Mac Feather'),
('MC3021',  'The Gourmet Microwave',    23, 'Michel DeFrance'),
('MC3021',  'The Gourmet Microwave',    23, 'Anne Ringer'),
('PC8888',  'Sestets of Silicon Valley',    20, 'Ann Dull'),
('PC8888',  'Secrets of Silicon Valley',    20, 'Sheryl Hunter'),
('PS1372',  'Computer Phobic AND Non-Phobic Individuals: Beha..',   23, 'Steams Mac Feather'),
('PS1372',  'Computer Phobic AND Non-Phobic Individuals: Beha..',   23, 'Livia Karsen'),
('PS2091',  'Is Anger the Enemy?',  23, 'Anne Ringer'),            
('PS2091',  'Is Anger the Enemy?',  23, 'Albert Ringer'),
('TC7777',  'Sushi. Anyone?',   23, 'Michael O''Leary')
```

Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT TITLEID,
               TITLE,
               AntalJaren,
               AUTHOR_NAME,
               'AUTHOR_'
               + CONVERT(VARCHAR(3), Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY TITLEID, TITLE ORDER BY TITLEID)) AS TEMP
        FROM   #Yourtable)A
       PIVOT (Max(AUTHOR_NAME)
             FOR TEMP IN ([AUTHOR_1],
                          [AUTHOR_2]))PV
```